Getting error while receiving message from Google Pub/Sub and loading it to Cloud SQL using Spring Batch
I am currently working with the Spring Framework and have been tasked with receiving messages from Google Cloud Pub/Sub and subsequently loading the data into Cloud SQL (PostgreSQL). To accomplish this, I have to utilize Spring Batch.
I have developed a basic application for testing purposes and have created a configuration class, PubSubConfig, where I am attempting to receive data from Pub/Sub. However, I am encountering an issue; specifically, the MessageChannel symbol cannot be resolved.
Could you please assist me in debugging this issue? Additionally, as I am new to the Spring Framework, any guidance or advice you could provide would be greatly appreciated.
// DemoApplication.java  (Main file)
package com.PubSub_Pipeline.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}


// PubSubMessage.java (POJO Clas)
package com.PubSub_Pipeline.demo.entity;


public class PubSubMessage {

    private String name;
    private String id;

    // Getters and Setters
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MessagePojo{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", id='" + id + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

// SpringBatchConfig,java (Batch Configuration File)

package com.PubSub_Pipeline.demo.config;

import com.PubSub_Pipeline.demo.entity.PubSubMessage;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.JobBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.builder.JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import java.util.List;



@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SpringBatchConfig {
    @Bean
    public Job job(JobRepository jobRepository,   Step pubSubStep) {
        return new JobBuilder("pubSubToCloudSQLJob", jobRepository)
                .start(pubSubStep)
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public Step pubSubStep(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager, ListItemReader<PubSubMessage> pubSubReader,
                           JdbcBatchItemWriter<PubSubMessage>writer
    ) {
        return new StepBuilder("pubSubStep", jobRepository)
                .<PubSubMessage, PubSubMessage>chunk(10, transactionManager)
                .reader(pubSubReader)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

    
    @Bean
    public ListItemReader<PubSubMessage> pubSubReader(List<PubSubMessage> messages) {
        return new ListItemReader<>(messages);

    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<PubSubMessage> writer(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<PubSubMessage>().
                itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>()).
                sql("Insert INTO message (id,name,email) VALUES (:id, :name, :email)").
                dataSource(dataSource).
                build();
    }
}



// PubSubConfig.java (File for receiving data from pub/sub)
package com.PubSub_Pipeline.demo.config;

import com.PubSub_Pipeline.demo.entity.PubSubMessage;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.core.PubSubTemplate;
import com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.integration.inbound.PubSubInboundChannelAdapter;
import com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.support.BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage;
import org.aspectj.bridge.MessageHandler;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;


@Configuration
public class PubSubConfig {

    @Bean
    public PubSubInboundChannelAdapter messageChannelAdapter(MessageChannel inputChannel, PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
        PubSubInboundChannelAdapter adapter =
                new PubSubInboundChannelAdapter(pubSubTemplate, "your-subscription-name");
        adapter.setOutputChannel(inputChannel);
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel inputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageHandler messageReceiver() {
        return message -> {
            BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage originalMessage =
                    message.getHeaders().get("gcp_pubsub_acknowledgement",
                            BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage.class);

            String json = (String) message.getPayload();
            // Parse the JSON message and acknowledge it
            PubSubMessage pubSubMessage = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, PubSubMessage.class);
            originalMessage.ack();
        };
    }
}


# application.properties

spring.application.name=demo

# Google Pub/Sub settings
spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.project-id=your-project-id
spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.subscription-name=your-subscription-name

# PostgreSQL database settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://<CLOUD_SQL_IP_ADDRESS>:5432/<DB_NAME>
spring.datasource.username=<DB_USER>
spring.datasource.password=<DB_PASSWORD>
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

# Spring Batch settings
spring.batch.job.enabled=true

I am creating an spring batch applications and getting error while using MessageChannel in my PubSubConfig.java . Please help me in debugging the application and additional guidance or advice will be helpful.

What error are you receiving? Please update your question to include a minimal repro of the error logs and/or stacktrace so that others may help

To accomplish this, I have to utilize Spring Batch.: Spring Batch is for batch processing, ie processing a fixed data set. A pub/sub topic or queue is not a fixed data set. So your use case is a streaming case rather than a batch case. While you can use Spring Batch for that, I think it is not the most natural fit for your requirement. A streaming solution would be more appropriate.

@MahmoudBenHassine I totally agree with you but it's client requirement. He want a near real time data pipeline in which whenever he publish the message into pub/sub then the data should be processed and load into cloud sql. I am getting difficulty while receiving message from pub/sub. If you have any resources please share with me.
